# pre loader in mvc in layout does not work in other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I **(newbie in MVC)** added a `preloader` with `jquery` in the `layout page`, which should be loaded on every `page load` in **MVC**.

The problem is it fires only on the `login` page, but does not fires on the subsequent pages. Is there any way to make it `generic` ?

```
......................
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        // Animate loader off screen
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .no-js #loader
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .js #loader
    {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 0;
    }

    .se-pre-con
    {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: url(images/Preloader_3.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        @Html.Action("Navbar", "Navbar", new { controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString(), action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() })

 <div id="page-wrapper">  
    <div id="main">
        <div class="ptcontainer">
<div id="loader" class="se-pre-con"></div>
            @RenderBody()

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is correct but you need to but slash to the background url image

```
background: url(/images/Preloader_3.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
```